# How to do wordpress api authentication in flutter

Tags: flutter, woocommerce-rest-api

I am making a flutter application in which in need to fetch data from backened API which is made in wordpress.Now in postman i only need to insert client key and client secret in Oauth 1 authentication and it works fine.But in flutter application it tell that the signature data is invalid.Why ?

I followed  official guide from woocommerce Api but i failed.How can i make wordpress api in flutter in dart?I am new to flutter and this is very important for me.So how can i fetch data ?Is there any method to achieve what i want ?

Comment: Please let us know if you found any solution.

Comment: No brother! i am following official doc from woocommerce but it doesnt works

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, you are looking for something like this

> 1. You want to display the products from wooCommerce using REST API.
> 2. And you want that to be done in Flutter Dart.
> 3. Auth for users.

The  very first thing will do is Auth the user using Username and Password so to do that we have to do something like this

**For Auth you should install the JWT plugin name JWT Authentication for
 WP-API in WordPress**

Then use this URL in the Flutter

```
    Future<http.Response> login(String username, String password) async {
    final http.Response response = await http.post('https://domina-name/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token?username=abc&password=xyz');
    print(response);
    return response;
  }
```

This function fetches the data from the wooCommerce REST API endpoints and stores in the List

```
List<CatService> category;

Future<void> getCategoryData() async {
var res = await http.get(
    "https://domain-name/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?per_page=100&consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=1");

setState(() {
  var data = json.decode(res.body);
  var list = data as List;
  print("List of cat $list");
  categoryList =
      list.map<CatService>((json) => CatService.fromJson(json)).toList();

  category = categoryList
      .where((data) => data.count > 0 && data.catName != 'Uncategorized')
      .toList();
});
```

}

Now you should call this future getCategoryData method like this

```
void initState() {
setState(() {
  this.getCategoryData();
});
super.initState();
```

}

I have created a class for CatService

```
class CatService {
  int catId;
  String catName;
  int count;

  CatService({this.catId, this.catName,this.count});

  factory CatService.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CatService(catId: json['id'], catName: json['name'],count: json['count']);
  }


}
```

Thanks, I hope this will help you